# How to define an URL ending with an integer?

Tags: swagger, openapi

The OpenAPI definition below will generate the URL as http://localhost:9200/GetCourse?id=1. How to change the definition to generate the URL as http://localhost:9200/GetCourse/1?

```yaml
  /GetCourse:
    get:
      summary: Get Courses
      description: >
        The GetCourse details.
      tags:
        - Content information
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: query
          description: The ID of the HEI being queried
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of courses
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Courses'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the parameter location (`in`) from `query` to `path`.
2. Add `/{id}` at the end of the path name.

```yaml
paths:
  /GetCourse/{id}:   # <----
    get:
      ...
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path   # <----
          description: The ID of the HEI being queried
          required: true
          type: integer
```